# Likelihood ratio test, given distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to find the implementable form for a likelihood ratio test and ran into a problem. Could anyone look at it an give me a hint? I'm stuck.

Here's the problem...

$X1,...Xn$  are distributed $ f(x;\theta) = \theta^{-1}x^{(1-\theta)/\theta}$

Theta is in $[0,\infty)$ and X is in [0,1]

I would like to run a LR test for $H0:\theta=\theta_0$, $Ha:\theta\neq\theta_0$

---

so far I have some progress. I have found that 
$\hat{\theta}_{MLE}={-\sum_1^nln(x_i)}/n$ which I found to be $Exp(\theta)$

$$y=-ln(x), e^{-y}=x$$
$$f(g^{-1}(y))|dg^{-1}(y)/dy|=\theta^{-1}e^{-y/\theta}$$ which is $exp(\theta)$

summing $n$ of those and then dividing by $n$ will give you an $Exp(\theta)$ distribution

after that I tried to run the LR test.

$$\Lambda=sup_{h0}L(x)/sup_\Theta L(x)=$$
$$\theta_0^{-n}\prod_1^nx_i^{1/\theta_0-1}/\hat{\theta_{MLE}}^{-n}\prod_1^nx_i^{1/\hat{\theta_{MLE}}^-1}$$
$$\theta_0^{-n}\prod_1^nx_i^{1/\theta_0}/\hat{\theta_{MLE}}^{-n}\prod_1^nx_i^{1/\hat{\theta_{MLE}}}=$$

$$(\hat{\theta_{MLE}}/\theta_0)^{n}\prod_1^nx_i^{1/\theta_0-1/\hat{\theta_{MLE}}}$$

and then I get stuck. Does anyone know where I can go from here?

Comment: If you plug in the value of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$ and use the relation $\prod_i x_i = \exp(-\sum \log  x_i)$ then you'll get the desired results.